# java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor strange logic

Tags: java, multithreading

Look ath this method of ThreadPoolExcecutor:

```
public void execute(Runnable command) {
    ...
        if (runState == RUNNING && workQueue.offer(command)) {
            if (runState != RUNNING || poolSize == 0)
                ensureQueuedTaskHandled(command);
        }
    ...
}
```

It check that `runState` is `RUNNING` and then the oposite. As I'm trying to do some tuning on a SEDA like model I wanted to understand the internals of the thread pool.
Do you think this code is correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The executor's runState can potentially change between the initial check and the subsequent check **after the command is added to the queue**.  One reason for this is if the executor's `shutdown()` method is called.

The second check is performed so that if the executor has been shut-down then any queued tasks are handled appropriately rather than being stranded on the queue.

Answer (score 2):

`runState` is `volatile`, so yes its state can change after initial check and a call to `workQueue.offer`